# problem finding upgrade rpm using yum with a multi cd installation

Tags: centos, yum, system-installation

Trying to upgrade `httpd` on from my install cd and having some problems.
On my test system, if disc 2 iso image is mounted on `/media/cdrom` and I run

```
yum -y -v --disablerepo=\* --enablerepo=my-media list httpd
```

NOTE: Latest version of httpd is on disc 2

it only shows the stock distribution of httpd:

```
Installed Packages
httpd.i686      2.2.15-29.el6.centos      @anaconda-CentOS-201311271240.i386/6.5
```

if Disc 2 is mounted `yum clean metadata` and `yum makecache` are run, yum still only list the stock `httpd` installation.

If I unmount disc 2 and mount disc 1 on `/media/cdrom` and then run

```
yum clean metadata --disablerepo=\* --enablerepo=my-media
yum makecache --disablerepo=\* --enablerepo=my-media
yum -y -v --disablerepo=\* --enablerepo=my-media list httpd
```

it then shows stock `httpd` install and the latest upgrade from `my-media`:

```
Installed Packages
httpd.i686     2.2.15-29.el6.centos       @anaconda-CentOS-201311271240.i386/6.5
Available Packages
httpd.i686     2.2.15-60.el6.centos.5     my-media
```

So, since the httpd rpm upgrade is located on disc 2, why does yum not know about it when disc 2 is mounted?? It only seems to know about it if disc 1 is mounted...Seems like a bug with `createrepo` to me??? or am I not understanding how it works entirely??

repo file:

```
[my-media]
name=MY-$releasever - Media
baseurl=file:///media/cdrom/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///media/cdrom/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
```

I am using CentOS 6.5 and created a multi set installation CD installation using `createrepo` with the `--split` parm

```
createrepo -v -d --split -u \"media://$discinfo\" -g repodata/comps.xml /tmp/build_dir_1 /tmp/build_dir_2
```

It reads both build directories and creates files necessary for a multi CD installation set just fine.